# session error-value fail to insert into DB

Tags: php, mysql, session

i have a php code that insert session value into database,but i get this error when trying to insert `Error: INSERT INTO tbale name (amount,bankname) VALUES ( 20000.00,gtbank)
Unknown column 'gtbank' in 'field list'`.the session  has the value GTBANK
below is my code that insert session value to database

```
    <?php

    session_start(); {



    //Include database connection details
    include('../../dbconnect.php');

    if($_SESSION["bn"]) {

}

$amount =  strip_tags($_POST['cat']);
$field1amount = $_POST['cat'];
$field2amount = $field1amount + ($field1amount*0.5);


$sql = "INSERT INTO provide_help (amount,bankname) VALUES ( $field1amount,".$_SESSION['bn'].")";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) 


$sql = "INSERT INTO gh (ph_id, amount) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), $field2amount)";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) 

 {
    $_SESSION['ph'] ="<center><div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>Request Accepted.</div></center>";
   header("location: PH.php");
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

anyone who can help please?.thanks

Comment: double quotes doing problem for you. better store session values in some variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bankname` field is type of `varchar` I think. So you need to pass string with quotes `''`. See below your code should be like this.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO provide_help (amount,bankname)
     VALUES ( $field1amount,'".$_SESSION['bn']."')";
```

Answer (score 2):

When inserting string (bankName) in data base it should be covered with quote.

Use this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO provide_help (amount,bankname) VALUES ( $field1amount,'".$_SESSION['bn']."')";
                                                                       // ^                   ^ --- Single quote added
```

---

I will suggest you to use [**bind_params**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) like following:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO provide_help (amount,bankname) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ds", $field1amount, $_SESSION['bn']);
if ($stmt->execute()){
    // handle success
} else {
    // handle error
}
```

The argument may be one of four types while binding:

```
i - integer
d - double
s - string
b - BLOB
```